Checking stochastic convergence and asymptotic normality of estimator.
I am stuck on the following problem:
Let $f$ be a measurable function with $f(x) = o(x) + x, x \rightarrow 0$.
Let $Y_n$ be a consistent and asymptotically normal estimator for $\lambda$.
Show $f(Y_n - \lambda)$ converges stochastically to 0 and is asymptotically normal.
Hint: First show: Let $X_n$ be a sequence of r.v. with $X_n \rightarrow 0$ stochastically. Show $\frac{X_n}{f(X_n)} \rightarrow 1$ stochastically.

I managed to proof the hint but am now unsure how to use that:
$\mathbb{P}[| \frac{X_n}{f(X_n)} - 1 | > \varepsilon ] \leq \mathbb{P}[| X_n | \geq \delta ] + \mathbb{P}[| \frac{X_n}{f(X_n)} - 1 | > \varepsilon | |X_n| < \delta] = \mathbb{P}[| X_n | \geq \delta ] +  \mathbb{P}[ \frac{|\frac{o(X_n)}{X_n}|}{|\frac{o(X_n)}{X_n} + 1|} > \varepsilon | |X_n| < \delta] \rightarrow 0 + 0$
since $|\frac{o(X_n)}{X_n}| \rightarrow 0$ for $|X_n$ small enough and therefore $\mathbb{P}[ \frac{|\frac{o(X_n)}{X_n}|}{|\frac{o(X_n)}{X_n} + 1|} > \varepsilon ] \rightarrow 0$ by Slutskys Theorem for $|X_n|$ small enough.

Firstly, "stochastic convergence" can mean a few different kinds of convergence according to Wikipedia. The kind that you mean, from the context of your proof, is convergence in probability.
I think your proof is overcomplicating things a bit. Define a function $g$ by $g(x) = \frac{x}{f(x)}$ for $x \neq0$ and $g(0)=1$, then $g$ is continuous at $0$. So for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x|\leq\delta$ implies $|g(x)-1|\leq\varepsilon$. Therefore
$$\mathbb P[|g(X_n)-1|>\varepsilon] \leq P[|X_n|>\delta] \to 0.$$
Now put $X_n = Y_n-\lambda$. By consistency, $Y_n-\lambda \to 0$ in probability, so the hint implies that
$$\frac{Y_n-\lambda}{f(Y_n-\lambda)}\to 1$$
in probability. Rewrite this as
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}(Y_n-\lambda)}{\sqrt{n}f(Y_n-\lambda)}\to 1.$$
By Asymptotic Normality, the numerator converges in distribution to a mean-zero Normal distribution. By Slutsky's theorem, the denominator does as well. The desired result follows.
